# Нормально ли то что я пользуюсь кодом и советами других во время прохождения курса Java?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, нормально ли когда я, на протяжении курса, советуюсь или беру готовый код и разбераю его, что б сделать задание?

Comment: Нет, так делать ни в коем случае нельзя.

Comment: чел, у тебя значит уровень логики 0%. Программирование - это 50% ЛОГИКА, 10% англ.яз., 40% знание ЯП